# Qual a forma mais adequada de instanciar um banco de dados num padrão MVC

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc, model

Estou estudando POO e um pouco sobre a estrutura MVC, e estou na dúvida onde criar e instanciar o banco de dados para ser usado na aplicação inteira, pensei que como o Model se relaciona com o tratamento de dados seria o melhor lugar para criar o escopo da classe, e como só as classes que estendessem o Model também usariam o banco, fiz da seguinte forma, exemplo:

```
Class Model {

    private static $db = null;
    private static $dbHost = 'localhost';
    private static $dbName = 'mini';
    private static $dbUser = 'root';
    private static $dbPass = '';
    private static $dbCharset = 'utf8';

    protected function __construct() {
        $this -> setConnection();
    }

    protected function getConnection() {
        return self::$db;
    }

    private function setConnection() {

        if (self::$db == null) {

            $op = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
            self::$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . self::$dbHost . ';dbname=' . self::$dbName . ';charset=' . self::$dbCharset, self::$dbUser, self::$dbPass, $op);
            return self::$db;
        }
    }

}

class userModel extends Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getUser() {

        $getAll = $this -> getConnection() -> prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
        $getAll -> execute();
        $test = $getAll -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $test;
    }

}
```

E a chamada, num controller, por exemplo seria da seguinte forma:

```
$userModel = new userModel;
$getUsers = $userModel -> getUser();
```

Esta é uma boa prática? e senão, por que? como sou novo nisso, alguns conceitos podem ser muito avançados ainda, por isso peço que expliquem de forma simples e gradativa.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é uma boa prática, inclusive este modelo é um padrão conhecido como [DAO (Data Access Object)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_de_acesso_a_dados), não em sua totalidade, mas o que você fez ai tem muitas características dele.

Algumas considerações do que você pode melhorar:

Aonde você coloca os dados de conexão:

```
private static $db = null;
private static $dbHost = 'localhost';
private static $dbName = 'mini';
private static $dbUser = 'root';
private static $dbPass = '';
private static $dbCharset = 'utf8';
```

**Jamais** coloque dados sensíveis de conexões em códigos. O que eu te aconselho é criar um arquivo `.env` no formato `ini` (você pode até chamar ele de `.env.ini` e utilizar a função `parse_ini_files` do PHP para le-lo. Neste arquivo, coloque suas configurações de conexão e banco de dados.

Agora para a minha segunda consideração, os objetos DAO, ou seja, são seus modelos de entidades, por exemplo, você possui a classe usuário que tem seu modelo, a classe usuário teria seu `UsuarioDAO` que seria o modelo que faria acesso ao banco de dados. Desta forma se torna necessário o uso de uma classe gerenciadora de conexões, um *pool* de conexões como eu chamo.

Este modelo utiliza o padrão [singleton](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) para retornar apenas uma única instancia que está conectada com o banco de forma que todos os objetos DAO utilizem a mesma conexão e não fiquem abrindo novas ao longo do tempo.

Eu aconselho que você utilize o modelo do gerenciador de conexões (uma nova classe) que será o responsável por servir uma conexão para todos os objetos que se conectam com o banco de dados.

A última observação que eu tenho seria para não ter um método que deixa a "query aberta", como você fez aqui:

```
   $getAll = $this -> getConnection() -> prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
```

Perceba o seguinte, você já deu um nome a essa ação: `getAll`, ou seja, um objeto DAO deve conter todas as ações que são possíveis para o mesmo, neste caso você deveria ter algumas do tipo: getAll, getOne, getByName, getById, etc...

É uma má prática deixar a query aberta, até porque se você o faz, o sentido em criar modelos de objetos se perde totalmente.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, sobre a primeira observação dos arquivos ini/env, mas assim não ficaria desprotegido para acesso direto? eu geralmente coloca tudo num config.php como constantes, na sua segunda observação eu não entendi muito bem a parte "seus modelos de entidades" o que são essas entidades? e sobre as querys abertas, sim, eu faço métodos genéricos no Model para todos "All, One, Byid", mas tinha escrito o código rápido só pra esclarecer minhas dúvidas, agradeço novamente por ter respondido.

Comment: E nesse exemplo que eu fiz,mesmo verificando se a variável $db está nula tem a chance de abrir outra conexão?

Comment: Entidades são tabelas, então os modelos das tabelas devem ser especificos e ter cada um seu conjunto de métodos. Quando ao arquivo ini, o formato ini fica indisponível para ser servido pelo webserver, então você tem que tirar o acesso direto